# Question surrounding centers of rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The center of a ring $R$ consists of elements that commute with every element of $R$:$$Z(R) := \{a \in R : ab = ba \text{ for all }b \in R\}.$$I know that $Z(R)$ is a commutative unital ring. I have two questions.

1. Does the center of the ring $\text{Mat}_n(F)$ of $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in a field $F$ consist of multiples of the identity matrix?
2. Do we have that $Z(R_1 \times R_2) = Z(R_1) \times Z(R_2)$?

Comment: What is your difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.

Let $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(F)$ be central. Let $E_{ij}$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix with $1$ as the $(i,j)$-th entry and zero otherwise.

Then $A E_{ii} = E_{ii} A$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$. But $A E_{ii}$ results from $A$ by deleting every column except the $i$-th and $E_{ii} A$ by deleting every row except the $i$-th. Thus $A$ must be diagonal.

If $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are the diagonal entries of $A$ then $A E_{ij} = \lambda_i E_{ij}$ and $E_{ij} A = \lambda_j E_{ij}$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, so $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$.

2. Yes.

That $(r_1, r_2) \in Z(R_1 \times R_2)$ is equivalent to
$$
 (r_1 s_1, r_2 s_2)
 = (r_1, r_2) (s_1, s_2)
 = (s_1, s_2) (r_1, r_2)
 = (s_1 r_1, s_2 r_2)
$$
for all $(s_1, s_2) \in R_1 \times R_2$. This is as the same as $r_1 s_1 = s_1 r_1$ for all $s_1 \in R_1$ and $r_2 s_2 = s_2 r_2$ for all $s_2 \in R_2$, i.e. $r_1 \in Z(R_1)$ and $r_2 \in Z(R_2)$.